# Creating an iOS or Android App from an existing backend

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Okay, so I've got a Postgres database hosted on a VPS at the moment, and I wanted to use this as a backend for a mobile app (Android **and** iPhone).

The current database stores public information about shops (name, address, postcode, city, phone). I wanted to use this data to build native apps for android and iphone with the following functionality:

- Get Local Stores using GeoLocation.
- In the case of GeoLocation not being available, fall back to grouping by city, allowing the user to select a city.
- Show the information for each store. (A show page).

I don't need any authorization, or access to any of the other device APIs, just geolocation.

Also, my speciality lies in web app development - I have zero experience with objective-c. Is there anything you folks would recommend?

**Note**: It needs to be deployable to the appstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really go with mobile web app frameworks if you're a web app developer.These frameworks are cross platform which is pretty useful and makes it a breeze for a web developer to have an app.

Something like these.

Sencha Touch - http://www.sencha.com/products/touch

jquery mobile - http://jquerymobile.com/

Titanium - http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/

Answer (score 0):

I second the mobile web app framework suggestion of @Serdar Dogruyol, but my personal favourite would be [Apache Cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/)